# browser auto-detect utf-8 ,hebrew

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, encoding, utf-8

hi i have a webapp in jsp

on an old tomcat entering my webapp ,the browser automaticly detect UTF-8

but when starting the same webapp in a fresh tomcat5.5,
browser wont detect UTF-8 ,i have to change it manually

(i am hosting my app now ,and i want it to work properly on a fresh tomcat)

tried to

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Content-Encoding","UTF-8");
```

but not helping , in some cases when i am trying to change to UTF-8 i still see jibrish

my jsp file i saved as UTF-8 and in meta i have this

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />`

also in server.xml i define this under the Connector

```
   URIEncoding="UTF-8"
```

--

can u help me please ?

Comment: And *is* the sequence of bytes you send to the browser in UTF-8?

Comment: how can i tell it to be, the file is encoded as UTF-8 isent the enogth ?

Comment: You keep saying that, but you don't sound certain of it.

Comment: solved it in a weird way , open in notepade where file located in the server , and make sure to save it as UTF-8 , this weird cause i setit to UTF-8 also in eclipse...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've still got the old app working, and you've got a (preferably simple) page that both servers can serve, I suggest you use [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) or [Fiddler](http://fiddlertool.com) to see exactly what's being sent back. Then you can work out the difference, and make the new server work the same way.

As Ignacio says, it may be that you're simply not serving UTF-8, however much you're trying to tell the client that you are :)